# How to calculate how much energy a body gets from a star?

Tags: energy, stars

Okay, so I could swear that I've seen an equation before for this (which I believe involved the Stephen-Boltzmann constant.) But now that I actually need it, much like my reading glasses I can't seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated as I'm sure this is a fairly easy problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A star is modelled pretty well as a blackbody so you use the formula,

$$ P = 4\pi R^2 \sigma T^4$$

to estimate the luminosity and then divide by $4\pi r^2$ to find the flux incident on an object a distance $r$ from the star.

$$ \frac{dE}{dt dA}=F = \frac{4\pi R^2\sigma T^4}{4\pi r^2}$$

---

In repsonse to the comment:

- $T$ : is the temperature fo the star
- $P$ : power radiated by the star (aka luminosity).
- $R$ : is the radius of th star.
- $\sigma$ : I the stefan-boltzmann constant.
- $F$ : Is the radiant flux at some point a distance $r$ from the star. (Units of $J/(m^2\cdot s )$)
- $dE$ : Increment in energy incident on a area $dA$ during a time $dt$.

---

In response to the OP's follow up questions:

The area $dA$ is the area of the object being hit by the light. For instance this might be a "CCD" in a digital camera.

$dt$ represents how long the are was exposed to the light.

$dE$ is the amount of energy that was delivered to the area during the time interval $dt$.

In case your not familiar with the notation of differentials the $d$'s represent a change or increment in the quantity the preced. $dt$ is a duration of time, $dE$ is an amount of energy, and $dA$ is a piece of area.

$$ dE = F \ dA  \ dt = \left( \frac{4\pi R^2\sigma T^4}{4\pi r^2}\right) dA \ dt $$

Comment: There's the part I was missing. I didn't realize that a star was essentially a blackbody. Could you please explain the second equation in a bit more detail? Mainly the dE, dA, and dt part. Also, is the area on the bottom of the second equation that of the star, the body the light from it is hitting, or a sphere between the star and the body? Sorry, I'm not very experienced in this field.

Comment: @user2925591, no worries I should have communicated more clearly from the outset. Does the edit I made clarify things?

Comment: Your upvoted and accepted answer is obviously mistaken. The second and third equations contain a blunder and are dimensionally incorrect. @user2925591

Comment: @RobJeffries, fixed now. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: OK, but leaving the comment for a while so the OP sees the change.